# Booleans in Python

Tags: python

The question is "Find an example where not(A and B) is different from not A and not B. Here, A and B are Booleans, that is, either True or False."

I have no idea how to get this started. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just start trying values of A and B.

Comment: From Mathematics or Logistic, "not(A and B)" equals to "not A or not B" which is different from "not A and not B"

Comment: There are only four possible permutations of values for A and B.  Where are you confused with running through each of them?

Comment: Maybe something like this to get started: http://ideone.com/9R0zeZ

Comment: [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
for a in [True,False]:
    for b in [True,False]:
```

For the selecting the values, and then generate the two truth tables.

Answer (score 1):

not(A and B) is different from not A and not B in any language, not only in Python.
It's easy to compare boolean functions by composing truth table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table